# Accessing values in multiple structures with similar names

Tags: matlab, eval

I'm reasonably new to Matlab, and have been trying to teach myself. I have looked for a similar question, but can't find one that's quite right.
In my workspace I have several structures with similar names. These structures will always start with the same word ('Base'), though the rest of the name will change ('1', '2', '3'), so for example `Base1`, `Base2`, `Base3`... etc. These variables were generated using the data cursor tool in a figure, so contain the fields `Target`, `Position` and `DataIndex`. I am only interested in the value in `Base*.Position(1,1)`. I would like to extract this value from each structure, as many times as there are structures (in one instance there may be 6 structures, another time only 4).
I am considering using the eval function, but it seems to work on exact strings rather than only the first part of a name. Additionally, a lot of documentation seems to advise against using eval.
So far I have:

```
clearvar except 'Base*'

list_variables=who;  

for i=1:length(list_variables)

    BaseTS(i) = eval('Base1.Position(1,1)');

end
```

It's the for loop I'm stuck on, as I don't know how to generalise so it will extract the value  .Position(1,1) for each different structure name.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having many structures called `Base1`, `Base2` etc rather put your structure in an array. Then you could rather call `Base(1).Position(1,1)`, `Base(2).Position...` etc. Your code will be more flexible and manageable this way.

So I suggest when you export using the data cursor, export to a variable called `Base_temp` and then immediately stick this into the next element of an array:

```
Base(end+1) = Base_temp
```

or even:

```
Position(end+1) = Base_temp.Position(1,1);
```

Then it's just a case of pressing up and enter after each time you export with the data cursor.

What you have read about avioding `eval` is correct, it's very rare (if ever) that `eval` is a good idea. It makes your code hard to read and very hard to debug. But since you're learning, this is how you could fix your loop. (But don't do this way, seriously don't, use arrays rather):

```
for i=1:length(list_variables)
    BaseTS(i) = eval(['Base', num2str(i), '.Position(1,1)']);
end
```

in other words use string concatenation to build up your string and use the looping variable (`i`) to get the different numbers. You'll need `num2str` to convert fromthe number to the string. But don't do it this way. This is a bad way.

Comment: +1 For detailed explanation and comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 0):

Dan's suggestion about avoiding `eval` is very valid. But if you decide to keep on the structures you have in your workspace, here's something without loops, but again `cellfun` seems to use loops internally. So, I guess this could be an alternative solution, with the not-so-popular `eval` -

```
list1 = who('Base*')
list2 = cellstr(strcat('BaseTS(',num2str([1:numel(list1)]'),')='));%%//'
ev1 = strcat(list2,list1,'.Position(1,1)');%%//'
cellfun(@evalc,ev1,'uni',0)
```